# OpenAPI Spring generator producing wrong dtos

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator

I have a couple of projects running OAS 3.0 and generating code using the Gradle OpenAPI generator, more specifically the Gradle plugin. I am using `JsonNullable` wrapped types and for the most part it seems that everything is OK. However I noticed the following behavior which does seem OK. Consider the following example:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    RequestDto:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          nullable: false
        name:
          type: string
          nullable: false
      required:
        - id
        - name
```

As you can see the `name` property is both **non-nullable** as well as **required** which in turns leads to the following code being generated:

```java
public class RequestDto implements Serializable {
    //Omitted noise
    private String name;

    public RequestDto name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     * @return name
    */
    @NotNull 
    @Schema(name = "name", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

In the above scenario all looks OK as the field is marked as **Required** and **@NotNull** which is correct. However when setting the field to `nullable: true` the following gets generated.

```java
public class RequestDto implements Serializable {
    //Omitted noise
    private String name;

  /**
   * Get name
   * @return name
  */
  @NotNull 
  @Schema(name = "name", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)
  @JsonProperty("name")
  public JsonNullable<String> getName() {
    return name;
  }

}
```

As you can see, the field is correctly wrapped in a `JsonNullable` wrapper and is also marked as `required`. However the `NotNull` annotation is still there meaning that I cannot pass in a request similar to:

```json
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": null
}
```

As this effectively fails when validating. I can easily bypass this by removing the validation annotation from the generated but this is not a viable solution as I need this to be in place.

My question thus is:

1. Do I understand something wrong, as my assumption is that a `nullable` and `required` field would allow `null` values as input regardless on whether those are wrapped in `JsonNullable`, in turn meaning no `NotNull` annotation.
2. How can I model `nullable` and at the same time required fields and get the generated code working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This indeed is a bit strange and complicated implementation and has also caught a lot of attention under [opeapi-generator issue](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/14765).

However as described to the ticket, this implementation looks intentional.

> Case 2: required=true & nullable=false We need to validate that the
> field is present but the developers should directly use the raw type
> -> Use JsonNullable to store the property, use the raw type on getter/setter, use a @Present annotation on the property (not on the
> getter) and a @NotNull on the getter for validation

To answer your question

> However the NotNull annotation is still there meaning that I cannot
> pass in a request similar to:
>
> `{   "id": 0,   "name": null }`

The above statement is not correct. You can actually pass the above request. Then the implementation will use the `@NotNull` just to ensure that a `JsonNullable` is returned from the getter.

When you open the `JsonNullable` with `requestDto.getName().get()` at this point you will get the contained `null` value.

The `@NotNull` in the getter is there to ensure that always a non null `JsonNullable` is returned.

Comment: Well, unless I am missing something what you mention above does not work. When passing in the mentioned payload, Spring will invoke the getter to retrieve this `null` value. Since the getter also provides the validation annotation (via `@NotNull`) it results in the mentioned error. Not sure how this can be mitigated.

Comment: Also you are correct. The `JsonNullable` field itself is not null, whereas it's wrapped value is. However even in this case the following validation error takes place `Field error in object 'requestDto' on field 'name': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.requestDto.name,NotNull.name,NotNull.org.openapitools.jackson.nullable.JsonNullable,NotNull];`

Comment: @akortex the field shall not be declared as `//Omitted noise private String name;` but as `private JsonNullable<String> name` Please check this again

Comment: Yes, it is declared that way the non wrapped one was simply a copy-paste error :).